# Make shapefile in ArcMap Editable in ArcGIS Collector

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-online, arcgis-10.6, arcgis-collector

I created a shapefile called random points in ArcMap. I assigned it a coordinate system, and I then shared as a hosted map service. Under Feature Access I checked Create, Delete, Query, Sync, and Update. Under the Sharing tab I checked the appropriate group.

When I accessed the Collector App, I was able to see the points I added as well as see its proper spatial location.

Though I was able to delete or edit a point, I was not able to see the add point feature. Under settings I also checked Add, Update, and delete features.

When I add another feature class I see the Add point feature in the collector app, but for some reason my recent created layers don't have the tab shown up.

I wonder if it's something I did not check off or took into consideration when creating my layer.

Comment: Do you see if the layer have a template for creating features? You can see this on feature service layer level and you can check the capabilities like Add Update Delete.